# Anaconda Nameerror

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, anaconda

```
from twitter import *

# Change to your keys
oauth_token = "aaa"
oauth_secret = "bbb"
consumer_key = "ccc"
consumer_secret = "ddd"

with open('football_terms.txt') as f:
    vocab = [term.replace('\n', '') for term in f.readlines()]

with open('football_teams.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        vocab.append(line.replace('\n', ''))

track_params = ','.join(vocab)

twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=OAuth(oauth_token, 
                                          oauth_secret, 
                                          consumer_key, 
                                          consumer_secret))

iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track=track_params,language='en')

for tweet in iterator:
    if 'text' in tweet:
        print tweet
```

When executing the program it gives error NameError:'TwitterStream' is not defined
even after installing twitter 1.15

Comment: If those are your real credentials, it would be good to edit them out here and change them on your account. It's also best not to import *, but to do something like `from twitter import TwitterStream`. In any case, I was able to run your code locally. Are you running in a virtualenv, with twitter installed in the virtualenv? https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: It's better to use conda environments, than virtualenv, especially if you are already using Anaconda.